# Git repos not working in Redmine with Gitorious

Tags: git, redmine, gitorious

I'm trying to add GIT repos to my redmine installation.

I'm using gitorious for my remo management. According to [Redmine & Git integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797774/redmine-git-integration) I added the script (http://blog.sofistes.net/2010/03/unhashing-gitorious-paths.html) wich makes symlinks to the repos. This all works fine.

But when I add such an repo to Redmine I get an error:

> 404 - The entry or revision was not found in the repository.

And in the log file (/var/www/redmine/default/production.log) I find:

> Processing RepositoriesController#show (for 192.168.1.100 at
>   2012-05-31 10:46:09) [GET]   Parameters: {"action"=>"show",
>   "id"=>"test-123", "controller"=>"repositories"} Rendering template
>   within layouts/base Rendering common/error (404) Completed in 169ms
>   (View: 42, DB: 8) | 404 Not Found
>   [http://redmine.test.com/projects/test-123/repository]

But when I create an git repo in, lets say, /var/www/test.com, and I add it (/var/www/test.com/.git/) to Redmine, it all words fine....

Both repos are owned by git:git and have the same permissions.

Does anybody have any suggestion what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> Both repos are owned by git:git and have the same permissions.

Repositories have the same permissions but the path may not be accessible by Redmine user. You may try adding git user to www-data group

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data git
```

Or set permissions explicitly to your repositories path:

```
sudo chmod 775 -R /projects
```