# Combine coding with multiple programmers

Tags: java, android, merge, programmers-notepad

As I mentioned in the title, can anyone recommend me a software which is easy to use and higher accuracy to merge program coding mainly Java(Android).

For example:
3 Programmers were writing ABC software.
First phase will be written by Programmer A & B.
Later, Programmer C will be involved and they are working at the same day.

Is there a software to let them upload their work onto a space and then compare the changes and merge it so that the next programmer is working on the latest version of code.

Extra Note: I have a CPanel account. If its possible to integrate. Or a standalone software will be accepted too.

Comment: Subversion. Just add a plugin to your ide and you're good to go.

Comment: Git. Better than Subversion :-)

Comment: @vojta I've worked with both and to me they are about equal in usability and usage. (Unless SVN made a lot of bad changed in two years since the last time I've used it ;) Currently I'm using GitHub for our C# WPF project, including the Visual Studio plugin for GIT.

Comment: Thank you very much for all your recommendations, I'll do more research on Git, Subversion and Redmine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a [Version Control System (VCS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control). Most popular are [Subversion](https://subversion.apache.org/) and [Git](http://git-scm.com/).

Answer (score 0):

git ,svn ,bitbucket,codeplex,sourceforge are mostly used tools.you can find more details on below blog.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_revision_control_software

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you REDMINE, that is a software to manage projects + GIT, an advanced control version tool.

see: [Redmine & Git integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2797774/redmine-git-integration)

```html
<iframe frameborder="0" width="480" height="270" src="//www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/xmifl2" allowfullscreen></iframe><br /><a href="http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xmifl2_add-git-repository-to-redmine_tech" target="_blank">Add Git Repository To Redmine</a> <i>por <a href="http://www.dailymotion.com/littlestreamsoftware" target="_blank">littlestreamsoftware</a></i>
```